# Add control to the parent control at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to add a control added at runtime to the parent control (panel)
I can set the properties of the object (PictureEdit) but how do i display it...add it to the parent control???
thank you

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
{
        PictureEdit halfmoon = new PictureEdit();
        halfmoon.Location = new Point(36, 3);
        halfmoon.BorderStyle = BorderStyles.NoBorder;
        halfmoon.Properties.SizeMode = PictureSizeMode.Squeeze;
        halfmoon.Image = Properties.Resources.picture;
}
```

Comment: How about `Controls.Add`? Seriously, this shows 0 research/attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: my parent object is in a different class...if you look closely this is onPaint override My PaintEventArgs does not have a control.add method

Comment: I would avoid trying to add a control anywhere in the OnPaint method as it would add a new control every time this control is repainted and that's not likely what you want. But @BradleyDotNET is correct in that you need a way to access Controls.Add.

Comment: That doesn't mean much. So if thats in a different class, how does it get access to this instance? Once it has it, you can add normally. You haven't shown nearly enough code to really help yet. And I wasn't suggesting using `Controls.Add` in the provided method, just in general :)

Comment: It's basically wrong, you have this code in OnPaint. Add the control in constructor for example.

Comment: I am trying to add the control every time the control is repainted. I have a panel control on the main form which i am overriding via the OnPaint event. I am creating the basic image framework in the OnPaint event but i also need to create a picture and add it to the parent control (my panel)

Comment: But the OnPaint event gets raised _a lot_ - basically everytime you move your mouse over the control. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: It will not get triggered when i move the mouse over but i get the idea. This is a static picture that i am building from squared and ellipses. On top of that i need to add a picture control (because it has more granular control over the image proprieties)

Answer (score 1):

```
Panel_name.Controls.Add(halfmoon);
```